# Get JSON object from an external url without JSONP

Tags: json

I am trying to get a JSON file from a url. It is stored on "abc.com", but I am working on "xyz.com".

I do not have access to change the JSON url or add CORS to the server.

You must be on our internal network to access "abc.com", so I can't use any sort of external proxy.

Is there any other way for me to get a JSON file from an external url?

Thanks

Comment: Not without going through a server, no.

Comment: You can do it server side from xyz.com

Comment: So if I add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in the header on xyz.com it will allow me to get the JSON with a XMLHTTPRequest?